# EMF use custom URIs for reference

Tags: eclipse, parsing, uri, emf

I need to use URIs with my protocol for references in EMF.

Then I need to write a parser for those URIs which returns standard URI for loading resources. Is it possible? Are there any examples for it?

Thanks.